# arp не ходит по бриджу с ядром 4.9

Tags: linux, l2tp, arp, bridge

Схема сети такая:

Есть интернет через

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.141
```

Через интернет создаю l2 линк.

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
tohs        8000.00a0c6000000   no      enx00a0c6000000
                            l2tpeth0
```

Особенность в том что на enx00a0c6000000 висит ip 192.168.0.1, который нельзя пробросить натом, нельзя поднять интерфейс с той же подсетью что и eth0. А получить доступ к устройству необходимо.

Вот такая картина на enx00a0c6000000

```
18:35:44.266301 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.0.1 tell 192.168.0.2, length 28
18:35:44.268230 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.0.1 is-at 5a:d2:e0:71:c5:21 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

но я не вижу ответов arp Reply на `l2tpeth0`. Арп от  `192.168.0.1 5a:d2:e0:71:c5:21` вообще не форвардятся.

интересный момент - задваиваются локальные маки:

```
# brctl showmacs tohs
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
  1 00:a0:c6:00:00:00   yes        0.00
  1 00:a0:c6:00:00:00   yes        0.00
  2 0a:d9:11:74:b0:4e   no         0.43
  1 5a:d2:e0:71:c5:21   no         0.42
  2 62:b7:5f:63:6a:d3   yes        0.00
  2 62:b7:5f:63:6a:d3   yes        0.00
```

l2tpeth0 линк работает - вынимал из бриджа и проверял.
Переменные sysctl проверял, iptables, arptables, ebtables чистые. Полдня просидел и так не понял почему нет форварда арп.

Откатил ядро на 3.16 - всё заработало и нет задвоения маков.

Comment: Что если попробовать сделать так: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1; sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce=2; sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter=0; sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`

Comment: попробую, но в другой раз. та машинка в работе